# php foreach showing old paragraph

Tags: php, foreach

I have created a script where every other word in a paragraph is green, which is correct. However there is a problem because the original paragraph which I used appears above the new paragraph, which I do not want.

This solution to this may be simple but I can't get my head around it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Code:

```
    <?php
$storyOfTheDay= "Once upon a time there was an old woman who loved baking gingerbread. She would bake gingerbread cookies, cakes, houses and gingerbread people, all decorated with chocolate and peppermint, caramel candies and colored frosting.

She lived with her husband on a farm at the edge of town. The sweet spicy smell of gingerbread brought children skipping and running to see what would be offered that day.

Unfortunately the children gobbled up the treats so fast that the old woman had a hard time keeping her supply of flour and spices to continue making the batches of gingerbread. Sometimes she suspected little hands of having reached through her kitchen window because gingerbread pieces and cookies would disappear.";

$storyOfTheDay = preg_split("/\s+/", $storyOfTheDay);

//Adding <span> to odd array index items
foreach (array_chunk($storyOfTheDay , 2) as $chunk) {
$storyOfTheDay[] = $chunk[0];
    if(!empty( $chunk[1]))
    {
       $storyOfTheDay[] = $chunk[1]= "<span style='color:green'>". $chunk[1] ."</span>";

    }
}


$storyOfTheDay = join(" ", $storyOfTheDay);

echo $storyOfTheDay;
```

Output:

[Image of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLJN1.jpg)

Comment: You are adding the second chunk to the first chunk, right here  $storyOfTheDay[] = $chunk[1]="

Comment: "the original paragraph which I used appears above the new paragraph, which I do not want." - does this mean there are multiple paragraphs we are not seeing in the code you posted? Because it looks like just one long paragraph in `$storyOfTheDay`

Comment: He means you're pushing the colored chunks to the same array that contains `preg_split("/\s+/", $storyOfTheDay);`.

Comment: Yes, one long paragraph is showing made up  the old and new paragraph ,it's joined the two paragraphs together.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bLJN1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are continuously filling the same array (`$storyOfTheDay`). Make the new one:

```
$storyOfTheDay = preg_split("/\s+/", $storyOfTheDay);

$newStoryOfTheDay = [];
//Adding <span> to odd array index items
foreach (array_chunk($storyOfTheDay , 2) as $chunk) {
    $newStoryOfTheDay[] = $chunk[0];
    if( !empty($chunk[1]) ){
       $newStoryOfTheDay[] = "<span style='color:green'>". $chunk[1] ."</span>";
    }
}

$newStoryOfTheDay = join(" ", $newStoryOfTheDay);
echo $newStoryOfTheDay;
```